# Angular 15 seems like is caching object

Tags: angular

I'm new on Angular, so I think there's a thing I'm not understanding correctly.

There's this array of objects containing a menu structure, like so:

```
...
{
    name: 'Admin',
    icon: 'extension',
    route: '#',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Creator',
        icon: 'work',
        route: 'creator',
        data: {
          expectedRoles: [PermissionRoles.Admin],
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Customer Manager',
        icon: 'group',
        route: 'customer-page',
        data: {
          expectedRoles: [PermissionRoles.Admin],
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Users Manager',
        icon: 'accessibility',
        route: 'users-manager',
        data: {
          expectedRoles: [PermissionRoles.Admin],
        },
      },
    ],
    data: {
      expectedRoles: [
        PermissionRoles.Admin,
        PermissionRoles.Admin,
      ],
    },
  },
```

So I'm exporting that:

```
export const NODES: Node[] = [array above];
```

and importing on my component:

```
import { NODES } from './constants';
```

But then when I'm reading the const value simply printing it via console.log on the ngInit cycle event:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     console.log(
       'NODES',
       NODES.find((i: any) => i.name == 'Admin')
     );
```

the children prop is coming empty, and if I just do a full reload in the page, then the children prop loads.

So, is there anything I'm doing wrong the way I'm  loading the NODES array?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The way you are loading the "nodes" is, in fact, correct. The problem here is different. As you can see, you are executing the console.log in the ngOnInit function, so whenever the component "inits" the console.log will execute. If you are accesing the component via router or any other way and the component is already initialized, the console log wont execute again, so you need to specify exactly when your console.log should execute, like after a redirection.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you for your reply, so the case here is difference between the moment I'm trying to read the NODES and the moment the NODES object is imported? I'm asking because there isn't processing with the object, so it should be the same information no matter the moment I read it, right?